# Is it possible to revoke file access with Swarm?

Tags: swarm

A file must be uploaded to a decentralized storage network since it is too big for the blockchain.

Only selected entities must be able to access it. Looking at the Swarm documentation, it says that the file author can grant permission to his file.

However, is it also possible to revoke that permission?